# Handling Special Characters With PHP & Linux

Tags: php, linux, special-characters

So, I got a PHP script that opens a file with a list of special characters such as  or ★ which look fine in my text editor, but when I saved it to my server all symbols in the list end up looking like "??".  How do I preserve these special characters?

EDIT: I figured out that the file itself is not saving to the server with the correct encoding. How do I solve this? The symbols look fine in my text editor (this is a text file btw) but after I save to server and reload via FTP it's all ?? instead.

Comment: How did you `save it to my server`.  Html, xml, css, text, pdf, jpg ... any code you used.  The issue is the character set, but it would be helpful to see how you are saving it.

Comment: just a simple .txt file with each character on a new line

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of the relevant code.

Comment: There really is no code, it seems to be happening when I save to the server because when I open through ftp I get the ?? instead of symbols

Comment: Have you tried using transfer type binary in your ftp software.

Comment: FTP is indeed set to Binary transfer mode. That's why I think it's the server itself. Linux Centos 6.6

Answer (score 2):

The character encoding of your page must match the character encoding used in your text editor.  If your page is loading utf-8 you must only use utf-8 encoded characters or you will see question marks.

Comment: The file itself seems to be saving to the server wrong, so it's not a display issue.